# How to load multiline csv feature into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, load-data-infile

I'm trying to load a .csv file into my SQL table, but one of the columns has data on multiple lines, and for some reason SQL doesn't like that. I've attached a picture of what my data looks like below, and I'm using the following command to load the data in:

```
load data local infile 'Users/.../info.csv'
into table spell_info fields terminated by ','
enclosed by ' ' lines terminated by '\n';
```

For some reason, it only loads the first row, basically it seems to just pop the first item. The response it gives me is

> 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column
> 'spellInfo' at row 1 Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

any help is appreciated. I'm not sure if it's the way the information in the csv file is listed or if it's my command, or some combination of the two.

[image]

Comment: Your fields aren't separate by `,` they are by a new line. And your "lines" aka rows are by two newlines. I'm not sure MySQL can take that overlap in identifiers. I'd be looking for a more structured file format or and application code to perform the parsing followed by inserting. Also components putting two values in the same column will make it very hard to search.

Comment: Please show the body of CSV file as code-formatted text, not a screenshot which shows this file interpretation in some table processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file to be imported uses more than one row per record then you have a lot of variants how to import the data correctly. I'll describe 2 of them.

## Variant 1.

The file is loaded into temporary table of the next structure:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    raw_data TEXT
);
```

The file is loaded into this table, the whole row is imported into one column. Like

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.ext'
INTO TABLE tmp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''        -- or use terminating char which is absent in the file
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'       -- use correct lines terminator
(raw_data);
```

Autoincremented column enumerates rows according to their loading order, i.e. according to their posession in the file.

After the data is loaded you may process this data and save the data into working table. If the amounts of lines per record is static then you may group the rows in temptable by `(id - 1) MOD @rows_per_record` and extract each separate column from definite row in a group. Or you may join according amount of rows by `t1.id = t2.id-1 = t3.id-2 = .. AND (tN.id MOD @rows_per_record)=0`. If the record data may occupy variable amount of rows then recursive CTE or iterative procedure may be the only option.

### Variant 2.

You use `LOAD DATA` with input preprocessing by the same way but load the whole line into user-defined variable. In SET clause you concat loaded value to saved one (in another variable) from the previous line loading and check if the line is complete. If so then you extract the values and save them into columns, and clear the variable which collects the data, if not then you fill the columns with fake but correct values. After the file is loaded you simply delete the rows with fake values.

---

If the file is not huge then you may load the whole file into one user-defined variable (use `LOAD_FILE()` function) and then parse it to separate records and columns.

Answer (score 0):

If your colomn with multiple lines is for example 'notes'.

The @notes variable is used to initially load the multiline "notes" field.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/yourfile.csv'
INTO TABLE your_table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(title, @notes)
SET notes = REPLACE(@notes, '\\n', '\n');
```

The SET notes = REPLACE(@notes, '\n', '\n'); part is an example and might need adjustment. It's intended to show how you could handle escaped newline characters within your CSV. However, if your CSV doesn't use escaped newlines within fields, this step might not be necessary.